# How to get user_id from wordpress database inside ajax function?

Tags: wp-query, functions, ajax, meta-query, id

I have an ajax function which switches the view type of the user's posts from list mode to grid mode via ajax but the problem is that when the wp query is being called it can't get the id of the user's profile that is being viewed. It works when I manually input an id number but it doesn''t work when I try to use things like $user->ID or $user_id or $user['ID']. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Here is my current php function and it's written inside my functions.php file:

```
function profile_view(){

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listings',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'stm_car_user',
                'value' => $user->ID
            )
        )
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
//$query = stm_user_listings_query('1', 'publish');

$response = array();

//Grid/list settings
$view_list = '';
$view_grid = '';
$view_map = '';
$current_link_args = array();
if(!empty($_GET)){
    $current_link_args = $_GET;
}

$view_list_link = $view_grid_link = $view_map_link = $current_link_args;
$view_list_link['view_type'] = 'list';
$view_grid_link['view_type'] = 'grid';
$view_map_link['view_type'] = 'map';


if(!empty($_GET['view_type'])) {
    if ( $_GET['view_type'] == 'list' ) {
        $view_list = 'active';
    } elseif ( $_GET['view_type'] == 'grid' ) {
        $view_grid = 'active';
        $current_link_args['view_type'] = 'grid';
    }
    elseif ( $_GET['view_type'] == 'map' ) {
        $view_map = 'active';
        $current_link_args['view_type'] = 'map';
    }
} else {
    $view_list = 'active';
}


    if ( $query->have_posts() ):
    ob_start();

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list-directory-loop';
    if(!empty($_GET['view_type']) and $_GET['view_type'] == 'grid') {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-grid-directory-loop';

    } elseif(!empty($_GET['view_type']) and $_GET['view_type'] == 'map') {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-map';

    } else {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list-directory-loop';

    }


    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        get_template_part($template);

    }

    $response['html'] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
else:

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

$show_pagination = true;
if(!empty($query->found_posts) and !empty($query->query_vars['posts_per_page'])) {
    if($query->found_posts < $query->query_vars['posts_per_page']) {
        $show_pagination = false;
    }
}

$response = json_encode( $response );

echo $response;
exit;
}

 add_action('wp_ajax_profile_view' , 'profile_view');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_profile_view','profile_view');
```

I'm not looking to use wp_get_current_user() either as that only shows posts from currently logged in users, I want to be able to see all posts by a certain user when I'm viewing their profile even when I'm not logged in...

Here is the ajax function:

```
$('.stm-view-by-profile a:not(.view-map)').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var viewType = $(this).data('view');
        $('#stm_view_type_profile').val(viewType);
        $('.stm-view-by-profile a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var data_form = $('.user_posts').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
            data: data_form + '&action=profile_view',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.stm-ajax-row').addClass('stm-loading');
            },
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
           $('.stm-isotope-sorting').html(data.html);
           $('.stm-ajax-row').removeClass('stm-loading');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: viewing what profile, where?

Comment: @Milo say for example I'm on www.mydomain.com/author/someauthor and there is a list of posts by that particular author and it's in list mode, I want to switch to grid mode on the click of a button by ajax and the above code works and switches it to grid mode but it doesn't display the correct posts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
You need to get the variable from AJAX in you case you need to do:

```
function profile_view() {
$user_id = $_GET["user_id"]; // name of hidden input

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listings',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'stm_car_user',
                'value' => $user_id
            )
        )
    );
...
```

Comment: That only shows posts from currently logged in users I don' want that, I want to be able to see all posts by a certain user when I'm viewing their profile even when I'm not logged in...

Comment: So, you need to pass a variable from JS to php with the user id?

Comment: Yes I just need the user_id to display or be fetched or be called or whatever...I can't find the correct method of doing so...

Comment: How do you call wp_ajax_profile_view? jQuery? And when do you call it?

Comment: I will edit my question and add it in and it's called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Last question, do you have the user id in the page where you have the button?

Comment: Yes it's on the form in a hidden input which is being serialized on the ajax call.

Comment: @MattH I edit the question I hope it resolves your question. Regards.